# Syntax Error when trying to make tables with Java DB

Tags: java, database

```
import java.sql.*;   // Needed for JDBC classes
public class StudentDB
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:StudentDB;create=true";

    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

        dropTables(conn);

        buildMichaelTable(conn);

        buildEvanTable(conn);

        buildJeffTable(conn);

        conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void dropTables(Connection conn)
{
    System.out.println("Checking for existing tables.");

    try
    {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        try
        {
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE Michael");
            System.out.println("Michael table dropped.");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE Evan");
            System.out.println("Evan table dropped.");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE Jeff");
            System.out.println("Jeff table dropped.");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {

        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void buildMichaelTable(Connection conn)
{
    try
    {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Michael (" +
                "MichaelName CHAR(25), " +
                "MichaelStudentID CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "MichaelClasses CHAR(25) " +
                "MichaelStudentGrades CHAR(5) " +
                ")");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Michael VALUES ( " +
                "'Michael Goldman', " +
                "'1216145', " +
                "'Programming II', " +
                "4.00 )");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Michael VALUES ( " +
                "' '," +
                "' '," +
                "'Cyber Law', " +
                "3.45 )" );

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Michael VALUES ( " +
                "' '," +
                "' '," +
                "'Operating Systems', " +
                "2.90 )");

        System.out.println("Michael table created.");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    }
public static void buildEvanTable(Connection conn)
{
    try
    {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Evan (" +
                "EvanName CHAR(25), " +
                "EvanStudentID CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "EvanClasses CHAR(25) " +
                "EvanStudentGrades CHAR(5) " +
                ")");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Evan VALUES ( " +
                "'Evan Bloom', " +
                "'1412179', " +
                "'Programming II', " +
                "3.45 )");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Evan VALUES ( " +
                "' '," +
                "' '," +
                "'Cyber Law', " +
                "4.00 )");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Evan VALUES ( " +
                "' '," +
                "' '," +
                "'Operating Systems', " +
                "2.90 )");

        System.out.println("Evan table created.");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    }
public static void buildJeffTable(Connection conn)
{
    try
    {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Jeff (" +
                "JeffName CHAR(25), " +
                "JeffStudentID CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "JeffClasses CHAR(25) " +
                "JeffStudentGrades CHAR(5) " +
                ")");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Jeff VALUES ( " +
                "'Jeff Royer', " +
                "'1592179', " +
                "'Programming II', " +
                "2.95 )");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Jeff VALUES ( " +
                "' '," +
                "' '," +
                "'Cyber Law', " +
                "1.72 )");

        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Jeff VALUES ( " +
                "' '," +
                "' '," +
                "'Operating Systems', " +
                "2.87 )");

        System.out.println("Jeff table created.");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    }
}
```

This is my first post I hope that I formatted it correctly. I am trying to make three tables of three different students using the Java DB but I keep on getting the errors:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "MichaelStudentGrades" at line 1, column 117.
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "EvanStudentGrades" at line 1, column 105.
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "JeffStudentGrades" at line 1, column 105.
```

I cannot find a syntax error, please help any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A comma is missing in the SQL code after MichaelClasses CHAR(25):

```
stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Michael (" +
                "MichaelName CHAR(25), " +
                "MichaelStudentID CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "MichaelClasses CHAR(25) " +
                "MichaelStudentGrades CHAR(5) " +
                ")");
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed the error, I also changed the studentgrades for all three to DOUBLE, but now I am getting ERROR: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL170704183307800' defined on 'MICHAEL'.

Comment: On stackoverflow you should ask questions about details that you cannot solve. You should not throw in a bunch of code and ask the community to solve all problems. I do see a design problem in the code: why do you have a table for each of the students? It is much more common to have a single table for all students. The table would then contain a column studentName or something like that. You create the table once and then insert the information for each student.

Comment: About the syntax errors: you should carefully watch where the syntax errors are coming from. If you build the application you can have syntax errors: these are Java syntax errors. If you run the application and get syntax errors, then they are probably SQL syntax errors. Look at the error message and carfully look at your SQL

Comment: about the duplicate key error: you have set field id to be a primary key. This means the all values of id have to be unique in the table. If you insert the same id twice, you will get a duplicate key error